# In a particular column, I want to handle pipe function as well as make use of a concat function at the same time. How can I achieve this? Query below

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata, hiveql

```
select regexp_replace(id,'["\t\n|]', '') as CONCAT('SF_',id) as id
      ,lastmodifiedbyid
      ,lastmodifieddate
from Enterprise_raw
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap one function into another one:

```
 select concat('SF_',regexp_replace(id,'["\\t\\n|]', '')) as id,
       ,lastmodifiedbyid
       ,lastmodifieddate
  from Enterprise_raw
```